# can i use lookup to display data extension column value?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, data

can i use lookup to display data extension column value?

I am trying to display name of the email recipient in email if EmailAdd_Column matches with the recipient email address.

In my case the audience data extension of an email is different from the data extension from which I want to pull the value. This is the reason I am thinking about usnig lookup.

I have this ampscript to pull Name but it is not working?

```
%%[
SET @pullname = LookupRows("DataExtensionName","NameColumn", "EmailAdd_Column", emailaddr)
]%%

Value from NameColumn is %%=v(@pullname)=%%
```

Answer (score 1):

The LookUpRows function is returning a rowset. You should use LookUp for this use case.

You would also have to use IF control for cases where it doesn't match i.e `Dear Customer`

Example:

```
%%[

var @pullname , @nullpullname /* It is best practice is always declare your variables */

SET @nullpullname = 'Dear Customer' /* This is just an example to help you see how / why you should add flow control to this */
SET @pullname = Lookup("DataExtensionName","NameColumn", "EmailAdd_Column", emailaddr)

]%%

%%[IF @pullname IS NOT EMPTY THEN]%%

%%=v(@pullname)=%%

%%[ELSE]%%

%%=v(@nullpullname)=%%


%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63242/discussion-between-kuml-and-data-kid).

Comment: Hi @kuml did my answer work for you?